# Splitting string by '/' failed, C

Tags: c, string, split

I wanna split a string by '/' and change char '/' to '/0' in the string, so I wrote a function like this:

```
void parse_query(char* str){
    char* p = str;
    char** r = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
    int i = 0;
    r[i++] = p;
    while(p=strchr(p,'/')){
        *p = '/0';
        p++;
        r[i++] = p;
    }
}
```

When I ran the program like below:

```
char* s = "a/b";
parse_query(s);
```

the segmentation fault occurred at this line:

```
*p = '/0';
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to change one character to 2 ('/' to "/0"), or change it to a zero character ('\0')?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
When I ran the program like below:

char* s = "a/b";
```

So you are modifying the string literal `"a/b"`, which is *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*. If you want to modify it, then use an array like this:

```
char s[] = "a/b";
parse_query(s);
```

In addition, you should do (as noted by AntonH):

```
*p = '\0';
```

or
`*p = 0;`

to terminate the string. `'/0'` is the different from `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
*p = '/0';
```

which is not actually one character, but two, with:

```
*p = '\0';
```

Which is replacing the value pointed to by `p` with a value of zero. Which is what I believe you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it should be `'\0'`, I think the segmentation fault stems from the fact that the string `"a/b"` is a literal, and these are generally stored in read-only memory. This means you probably can't write to that memory, and if you try, you get a segmentation fault.

Make a copy of the literal string into a writeable buffer and try it on that. I bet it works then.

Comment: You mean `'\0'` rather than `"\0"`, no?

Comment: @AntonH: Yes, of course. <slapping my forehead>